# E: Unable to locate package when I install unetbootin

Tags: software-installation, 18.10, unetbootin

I try to install UNETbootin using the terminal. When I enter the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install unetbootin
```

I get this error:

```
E: Unable to locate package
```

I already tried many things.

I hope anyone has a solution for this? I'm using Ubuntu 18.10 is it because of this version I get this error? Are there other alternatives than unetbootin?

Answer (score 2):

Three moments here:

1. UNetBootin was available in the *universe* repository for [14.04 LTS and 16.04 LTS](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=unetbootin).
2. UNetBootin's PPA [`ppa:gezakovacs/ppa`](https://launchpad.net/~gezakovacs/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) do not have packages for 18.10.
3. You still can install it by manually downloading packages from 18.04 LTS PPA:

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads
   wget https://launchpad.net/~gezakovacs/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+files/unetbootin_667-1~bionic2_amd64.deb
   wget https://launchpad.net/~gezakovacs/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+files/unetbootin-translations_667-1~bionic2_all.deb
   sudo apt install ./unetbootin*.deb
   ```

---

Note: I have sent e-mail to UNetBootin PPA owner about supporting of 18.10.

Answer (score 2):

UNetbootin has been dropped from the default Ubuntu repositories in 18.04 and later, but the built-in Startup Disk Creator application is a good alternative to UNetbootin for the 5 live Linux USBs that I made with Startup Disk Creator instead of UNetbootin so far. My cumulative success rate with Startup Disk Creator as a UNetbootin alternative is 5 out of 5.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting this. I was also able to use it to write a Gparted Live image to a flash drive.